# Randomly select multiple rows and randomly update multiple rows between 2 tables (Laravel eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

I have a situation like this
My mysql has 2 tables product_queue and description
I want to randomize multiple rows of content of column 'content' in descripton table to randomly update multiple rows into 'descripton' column of product_queue table provided that store_id column of 2 tables must be equal

[Image description table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRcsz.png)

[Image Product_queue table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nF6N.png)

I tried this code but it didn't

```
$descriptions = DescriptionModel::orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
foreach ($descriptions as $description) {
      ProductQueue::where('store_id', $description->store_id)
      ->update(['description' => $description->content]);
}
```

Before I ask a question, I have also tried on the forum

Answer (score 0):

use this to get random records from db
`$data = DB::table('table_name')->inRandomOrder()->limit(50)->get();`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $descriptions = DescriptionModel::inRandomOrder()->get();
 $descriptions = DescriptionModel::inRandomOrder()->limit(20)->get(); // get 20 random records
```

or:

```
 $descriptions = DescriptionModel::all()->random(); 
 $descriptions = DescriptionModel::all()->random(20); // get 20 random records
```

Comment: Thank you 
The problem of selecting random records in table 'description' seems fine, but how can I update multiple rows in table 'product queue' Can you give me a specific solution?

Comment: mmm can you try this code ?  ProductQueue::where('store_id', $description['store_id'])
      ->update(['description' => $description['content'] ]);

Comment: Thanks for answering @Gene_Nostrada
What I mean is how to update many rows in the product_queue table without having duplicate data

Comment: okay mate  you can use ProductQueue::where('store_id', $description['store_id']) ->updateOrCreate(['description' => $description['content'] ]);  usually updateOrCreate have to stop duplicate since it will update if exist and create if it's not exist